# Issue applying includes string method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code, and yet am getting a very confusing result.

Here's a simple function:

```
const test2 = () => {
  let containsBitcoin = false
  const str2 = "buy bitcoin"
  if (str2.includes('bitcoin')) {
    let containsBitcoin = true
  }
  return containsBitcoin
}
```

But when I console.log the result with

```
console.log(test2())
```

I get false. I can't figure out why.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-playground99?file=index.js)

Comment: `let containsBitcoin = true` ----> `containsBitcoin = true`

Comment: @Yousaf or alternatively `let containsBitcoin = str2.includes('bitcoin')` without an `if`

Comment: @VLAZ right. OP's code can be simplified even further: `return str2.includes('bitcoin')` but instead of suggesting a different approach, i just wanted to point out the mistake in the OP's code.

Comment: @Yousaf TBH it can be simplified to `true` since the string is static. But the point is that the problem lies in declaring a new variable in the block scope. The solution is either to re-use the variable or don't have the block scope (and a redeclaration) at all.

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because you are redeclaring the `containsBitcoin` inside your condition instead of changing its value, while the value of `containsBitcoin` for outer scope remains false.

```js
const test2 = () => {
  let containsBitcoin = false
  const str2 = "buy bitcoin"
  if (str2.includes('bitcoin')) {
     containsBitcoin = true
  }
  return containsBitcoin
}
console.log(test2())
```

Comment: I was just about to write the same thing, but you beat me to it.